How to go about finding polynomial from specified monodromy?
I want to find the polynomial $p(x,y)=0$ that corresponds to a four-sheeted Riemann surface with monodromy $(123),(132),(124),(142)$ at four branch points. Such a surface is genus 1, but I'm struggling to find the associated polynomial.
I know no algorithm exists in full generality, but perhaps there are some techniques that could help for this low-genus, low-degree example?
(@alexandre Eremenko looks like I can't comment, but yes, an explicit construction is what I want. I agree that existence is trivial).

It depends on the exact meaning of the word "finding". Do you want it to be expressed by some algebraic expression, with algebraic coefficients? Existence is easy: just construct a Riemann surface.

The main technique I can think of is to choose the location of the branch points to maximize symmetry and then see what symmetries extend to symmetries of the surface. If you get an automorphism of order three or larger fixing a point you know which curve to take, and then the symmetries can further constrain what the map to $\mathbb P^1$ must be.

In 2007 I wrote a short note (in German) on how to determine all elliptic curves with prescribed ramification over $\mathbb{P}^1$. It can be found on http://www.aviduratas.de/wiss-math-synop.html (look for eccov.pdf). I am not quite sure if there is an error hidden inside as no one besides me ever read it and I also did not try an implementation on a computer algebra system - maybe you (or some other reader of this post) might be interested to give it a look.

I just corrected a mistake in my note from 2007 mentioned above that I noticed upon rereading - strangely it was in principle corrected in the newest tex source but did not make it into the pdf. Now the pdf should be correct (at least in this respect) (the mistake consisted in the treatment of the expression $\frac{d^\nu h^{(j)}}{dx^\nu}$.)

I went through the note mentioned above a second time and corrected an important oversight. I overlooked two additional degrees of freedom and three constraints and with them now got 2 free parameters instead of 3 before, which was one more than reasonably to expect.

We will construct a polynomial $p(X, Y)\in\mathbb C[X, Y]$ such that the Riemann surface given by $p=0$ has genus $1$ and the covering to the $X$-line has the requested ramification.
In order to do so, we use the more convenient language of function fields. Thus, for a transcendental $x$ we construct the field extension $\mathbb C(x)\subset\mathbb C(x,y)$ which has the requested ramification.
We will proceed by a translation technique using suitable extensions of rational function fields $\mathbb C(t)\subset\mathbb C(y)$ and $\mathbb C(t)\subset\mathbb C(x)$.
For the first extension, we use a degree $4$ extension with monodromy generators $\sigma_1=(1,3,2)$, $\sigma_2=(2,3,4)$, $\sigma_3=(1,2,4)$, and for the second extension we use one with monodromy generators $(1, 2, 3)$, $(1, 2, 4)$, $(1, 4)(2, 3)$, where the branch points match accordingly.
Now, by Theorem 7.3 (first subcase of case (b)) in Inverse Galois Theory by Malle and Matzat, the monodromy generators of the extension $\mathbb C(x)\subset\mathbb C(x,y)$ are given by
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1^2,\; (\sigma_1^2)^{\sigma_3^{-1}\sigma_1},\; \sigma_2^3,\; \sigma_2^{\sigma_3^{-2}\sigma_2^2},\; (\sigma_3^3)^{\sigma_2^2},\; \sigma_3.
\end{equation}
For our specific $\sigma_i$'s we obtain (dropping the two elements of order $1$)
\begin{equation}
S = (1,2,3), (2,4,3), (1,3,2), (1,2,4).
\end{equation}
We will show that this tuple is equivalent under the action of the Artin braid group to the requested tuple
\begin{equation}
E = (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (1, 2, 4), (1, 4, 2).
\end{equation}
Let $B_i$ be the generator of the Artin braid group which replaces the elements $a,b$ in positions $i,i+1$ with $b,b^{-1}ab$. Then we get from $S$ to $E$ via
\begin{align}
S
&= (1,2,3), (2,4,3), (1,3,2), (1,2,4)\\
&\xrightarrow{B_2} (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (1,4,2), (1,2,4)\\
&\xrightarrow{B_3} (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (1,2,4), (1,4,2)\\
&= E
\end{align}
It is not hard to explicitly compute the two field extensions: Both are given as rational functions $A$ and $B$, and the requested polynomial $p(x,y)$ then is the numerator of $A(x)-B(y)$.
For instance, the curve given by $p(X, Y)=0$ where
\begin{equation}
p(X,Y) =  4X(Y^4 - 6Y^2 - 3) - Y(X^4 - 12X^3 + 30X^2 + 4X + 9)
\end{equation}
has the requested ramification over the $X$-line.
We can confirm this with Magma's online calculator. The code
R<x,y> := PolynomialRing(Rationals(),2);
p := 4*x*(y^4 - 6*y^2 - 3) - y*(x^4 - 12*x^3 + 30*x^2 + 4*x + 9);
X := RiemannSurface(p);
print MonodromyRepresentation(X);

yields the monodromy generators
\begin{equation}
M = (2, 4, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 4, 2), (2, 3, 4).
\end{equation}
To confirm that the example is correct we need to show that $M$ is Artin braid equivalent to $E$. As $S$ and $E$ are equivalent, we can use the shorter path from $S$ to $M$:
\begin{align}
S
&= (1,2,3), (2,4,3), (1,3,2), (1,2,4)\\
&\xrightarrow{B_1} (2,4,3), (1,4,2), (1,3,2), (1,2,4)\\
&\xrightarrow{B_3} (2,4,3), (1,4,2), (1,2,4), (2,3,4)\\
&\xrightarrow{B_2} (2,4,3), (1,2,4), (1,4,2), (2,3,4)\\
&= M
\end{align}

The same trick works more generally when starting with a (genus-0) quartic with ramification type "two transpositions and two 3-cycles", and pulling back by a quadratic ("two transpositions"). I haven't thought of a good reason why the result of the pullback lands in the "right" of the two possible braid orbits for type $(3,3,3,3)$ in $A_4$, but Magma says it does.Since the starting cover has 4 branch points, this also has the advantage of giving a whole family of (non-equivalent, even up to $PGL_2$-action) covers; concretely $f_t(X,Y)=Y^2(tY^2+8tY+18(t-1))-X^2(9Y^2+8tY+2t(t-1))$ works.

@JoachimKönig Very nice!
